# Unable to get the textarea value of a ckeditor textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I'm unable to get the value of the `textarea` when I use CKEditor. I'm using Ajax form submit when I use the normal `textarea` then the value gets submitted to the database no issues but when I use CKEditor the data submit without the `textarea` value.

```html
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Add Body" id="discription" name="discription"></textarea>
```

the above is the `textarea`

```js
CKEDITOR.replace( 'discription' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, CKEditor got its own way to get `textarea` value. So you should do it like this:

```js
// bracket notation
const textareaValue = CKEDITOR.instances['discription'].getData();
```

Or

```js
// dot notation
const textareaValue = CKEDITOR.instances.discription.getData();
```